# How to filter the values inside [ngForOf] in Angular2?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-template

[pipe in angular2 ngForOf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uK0z7.jpg)I am new to Angular. Right now I am learning ngForOf concept. I am trying to work on how to bind the variable inside ngForOf directive. Please find the following codes.In AngularJS we can directly bind the values in ng-repeat but what can I do in Angular2?

app.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
  <h1>{{title}}</h1>


  <ng-template ngFor let-item [ngForOf]="heroes" let-i="index">
    <li>{{item}}</li>
  </ng-template>
`
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'Tour of Heroes';
  heroes = ['Windstorm', 'Bombasto', 'Magneta', 'Tornado'];

}
```

In the above code I am successfully able to display heroes array content.

Now, I want to apply the pipe on heroes and filter the data based on pipe and then to display the filtered data.

app.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
  <h1>{{title}}</h1>


  <ng-template ngFor let-item [ngForOf]="filteredData = (heroes | pipename : "data for pipe" " let-i="index">
    <li>{{item}}</li>
  </ng-template>
`
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'Tour of Heroes';
  heroes = ['Windstorm', 'Bombasto', 'Magneta', 'Tornado'];

}
```

Looking forward for any kind of help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have answered pretty much the same issue earlier on another question, this might just help you. If not, feel free to comment and I will assist.

[how to create a custom sorting pipe in angular 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48995330/how-to-create-a-custom-sorting-pipe-in-angular-4/48995574#48995574)

To make it short: Don't use a pipe for that. Filter and sort in the component when you pass the data.

Comment: My problem is, I need to display the filtered data length every time the search is done. For example, please find the attached image.

Comment: In the attached image, they are not displaying the results based on search data. I need to display the filtered data length after every successful search operation.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you still want to be able to access the original data / original array length. But even if you filter it in the component, that would still work. You can set a variable filteredHeroes and use that for your iteration instead, then still have the heroes variable to access the original values.

I am not 100% sure yet whether that is what you are after.